# Windows key + right/left arrow keys doesn't work on undecorated frame in swing

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

I have an undecorated ( **setUndecorated(true)** ) frame which doesn't behave properly when pressing windows key + right/left arrow keys.

Please refer the sample code bellow :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestGUI {

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing") {
            @Override
            public boolean isUndecorated() {
                return super.isUndecorated();
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But when I set the frame as **setUndecorated(false)**, then it works properly. I couldn't find any java bug related to this issue. Is there a work around which I could use to get the same behavior with **setUndecorated(true)**?

Comment: It's not a java-Bug. Support of windows key + right/left arrow keys is provided by the native Windows decoration, so if you turn it off, you can not use it.

Comment: BTW - it's not clear what the question is, given there was no question asked. What is the *question*?

Comment: Sorry Andrew. I updated the question.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy. The problem is winkey + up/down arrows is working as expected. That's why I thought it was a bug in java.